# Pre fill google contact add form from url query field

Tags: query-string, contacts, google-contacts-api

I want to add a feature in admin panel, in which when admin click on phone number, it will redirect to [google contact add url](https://contacts.google.com/new) and I will pass customer data in query URL. This query data will automatically pre-fill in google contact form.

Using this URL

```
https://contacts.google.com/new?email=test@example.com&phone=0000000000
```

I can pre-fill Email and phone number. But i also want to pre-fill First Name, Surname, Labels, Country Code, DOB.

I tried with various query parameters like `firstName`,`firstname`, `first_name` etc. But none of them worked other than this `email` and `phone`.

Answer (score 0):

I landed on this after trying a few things.

https://contacts.google.com/new?email=jack@example.com&familyname=Smith&givenname=Jack

I got the idea to try "givenname" from this gist:

https://gist.github.com/samkit5495/ff8e2a6644363cadaec3fa22ddf38c90